# How to implement clickable LabelField.

Tags: blackberry

I need to create a `LabelField` which can perform click action. I have overrided `navigationClick(int status, int time)`. But when I click on that `LabelField`, MenuButton popup is appearing. How to disable it. The code I'm using is given below:

```
LabelField pdtitem = new LabelField(pdts.getProducts_name(),LabelField.FOCUSABLE) {
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        Dialog.alert("hai");
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new desc());
        return super.navigationClick(status, time);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consume event in your navigationClick() method.

`return true` instead of `return super.navigationClick(status, time)`;